# How to solve $ dx = (\sin y + 3 \cos y + x) dy $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

How could I solve this? I guess I need to use integration factor, but I do not understand it very well.

$ dx = (\sin y + 3 \cos y + x) dy $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $x$ as a function of $y$. Then the equation can be written as
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=x+\sin y+3\cos y.
$$
This is a linear equation.

Comment: I feel stupid now, I didn't realized that it could be x(y). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is just unusual to have $x$ and $y$ switched:
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} - x = \sin y + 3 \cos y
$$
And yes, an integrating factor exists:, multiplying both sides with $e^{-y}$ gives:
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\left(x e^{-y} \right) = 
e^{-y}\left(\sin y + 3 \cos y \right) \Rightarrow \\
$$
\begin{align}
x 
&= 
e^y \int\limits_{y_0}^y e^{-\hat {y}}\left(\sin \hat{y} + 3 \cos \hat{y} \right) \, d\hat{y} + x_0 \\
&=
e^y \left[e^{-\hat {y}}\left(\sin \hat{y} - 2 \cos \hat{y} \right) \right]_{y_0}^y + x_0 \\
&=
\sin y - 2 \cos y - e^{y-y_0} \left( \sin y_0 - 2 \cos y_0 \right) + x_0 \\
\end{align}